# Why is my POM.xml file so short (I'm trying to use Mocks)?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mocking, mockito

so I have Maven installed on my Eclipse, and I downloaded it from the store. However, when I put the import statements for mocking, I get

```
The import org.mockito cannot be resolved
```

and the rest x next to it.

My XML file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>BlackJack</groupId>
  <artifactId>BlackJack</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: @StephenC there's a million tutorials with very different problems than I have. I don't know why helping me would be so bad.

Comment: Try the official ones.  Or the official Maven book. The point is not to solve >>this<< particular problem.  The point is that you need to learn how to use Maven properly.   Yea, sure, we could teach you to use Maven the hard way ... by answering all of your questions.  But it is much more efficient for everyone if you spend the effort up front on doing some reading.

Comment: *"I don't know why helping me would be so bad."* - Because ... it won't actually help you learn.  (Or at least ... learn properly what you need to know.)   And, actually, telling you that you need to go do some reading *is* helping you.

Answer (score 1):

The below pom.xml would suffices your requirement and 
  this [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/21816/mockito-tutorial) will help you for better understanding how to work with mockito using maven

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
          <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
          <groupId>BlackJack</groupId>
          <artifactId>BlackJack</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
          <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                  <source>1.8</source>
                  <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
          </build>
        </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven has to download the dependencies, so you have to specify the package you're trying to import in the pom file. Go to https://mvnrepository.com and search for your package. Find the latest version, and you'll see under the maven tab something like this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You put these in between `<dependencies></dependencies>` somewhere in your project tags.

Comment: can you find a link for me, from what I've given? I don't know what package you're telling me to search for.